# Java (eclipse) properties.config file setting values between issue

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven-3

I am using eclipse and calling a SQL Select statement with values between and receiving errors.
Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong? I am getting error as: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression`

Below is my query:

```
getData =  Select [ID],[Make],[Model],[Year] from [dbo].[TestData] Where [ID] between (( \= pageNumb*10) + 1) and ( \= pageNumb+1)*10
```

Also, how to write the SQL connection string ?

```
dbConnStr=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:test_user/Password$_@//mnop23.test.corp\:5001/mnop23.WORLD
```

How to write SQL connection string in this format ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) for an example.
It should as simple as this.
DB_URL= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myorcldbservicename";